# How can I put functions in different files, but get them all with just one import?

Tags: python, python-import

Instead of creating a module.py (containing all the functions), can I create a folder MODULE and collect all the functions in different files?

I'd like to do that in a way that main.py contains `import MODULE` and, if it's possible, to call the functions directly (`fun_1()`, `fun_2())` without the nomenclature `MODULE.fun_1()`, `MODULE.fun_2()`, etc.

Comment: Note that wildcard imports (copying everything from a module's namespace into your namespace) are generally accepted as a bad idea, and for good reason. `module.fun1()` might look like more work, but when you're importing 20 different modules, someone who's reading your code will need to know which one `fun1` comes from to make sense of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only right way is creating `__init__.py` (import all functions contained in other files) in your MODULE folder. And use statement `from MODULE import *`. If you wanna use `import MODULE` and call func in other files then, that never work. Interpreter will raise the `NameError`, cause there are no the variables.

`__init__.py` file like this:

```py
from file1 import func_1
from file2 import func_2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Create your main file, `main.py` along with another file where you want to put another function. I will use the `other.py` file.

In `main.py`, write

```py
from other import *
```

Note the missing `.py`, Python handles that for you.

In `other.py`, write

```
def your_function():
    return -1
```

You can have as many functions in here as you want. Now, you can call `your_function()` in `main.py`.

Example Repl.it: https://repl.it/repls/MeaslyBurdensomeDesigners

Comment: The OP is asking how to have an implicit `import *` -- they don't want to run `other.your_function()`, but just `your_function()`.

Comment: okay but in this way I have to store all the functions in other.py.
I'd like to use n file for n functions, and store all of the functions in a folder.

Comment: @sdn-96, for that, have an `__init__.py` in the folder that imports from the individual files. We have other answered questions that already show how to do this.